# Reversible Transformer and LSH vs. SOA Models

Tags: llama-2, transformers

In the DeepLearning.ai specialization on Natural Language Processing, the instructor claims that the [Reformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04451), using LSH and reversible layers, is able to ingest context lengths of 1M+ tokens and still perform equivalently well to a traditional transformer. If this is the case, why do we continue to see state of the art models (Llama-2, GPT-3, Palm2, Falcon180B, etc.) that use standard transformers and are limited to significantly shorter context lengths (4k and 16k are common).

Why don’t state of the art models use the reversible transfomer architecture?